# jQuery .NoConflict Script Load

Tags: prototypejs, conflict, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery in a highly conflict environment. .noConflict() doesn't work and I am trying to do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
jQuery.noConflict();
var $ = jQuery;
</script>
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: I would concentrate on why noConflict doesn't work and not trying to hack my own solution. What exactly is the problem with noConflict?

Comment: hi - everytime I include even the jQuery script - I get conflicts with prototype. i.e. just inserting the <script type="text/javascript" src='path/to/google/jquery/'></script> gets me conflicts so I am trying to wrap the script

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'conflicts' upon insert? They should occur only after some action is taken, further down the page

Comment: get [ element.dispatchEvent(event);  element.attachEvent("ondataavailable", responder); element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder);  element.dispatchEvent(event); ] all get error = element.dispatchEvent is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it has nothing to do with the fact that you have:

```
document.write(    document.write(unescape(...longstringhere...)); // Missing final close paren?
```

That would cause an error and then `noConflict` wouldn't work.

Also, do you need to be using Prototype and jQuery at the same time? The whole purpose of `jQuery.noConflict()` is to NOT set the `jQuery` variable to `$` because Prototype uses it (I'm sure there are other reasons, but that's the main one in this case). jQuery and Prototype aren't good friends, usually.

Finally, are you absolutely positive (assuming you don't have the syntax error in your real code) that jQuery is getting loaded?

---

Did some quick research. Check this link and see if it helps any:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Basically, you might have to call jQuery first, and you will have to call Prototype BEFORE you use `noConflict()`

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I was able to help you solve the problem. =)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$` - that is the source of the conflicts. Substitute `jQuery` wherever you'd normally use it, like so:

```
jQuery('#my-id')
jQuery('.my-class')
```

and so on